# Вёрстка исчезающей линии

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!

Как сверстать такую линию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Градиентом

```css
.text {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #027abe;
}

hr {
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #027abe 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Main content listing header.</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам))))

Comment: @АлександрЖариченко, можете отметить мой вопрос, как правильный :)

Answer (score 1):

Линейным градиентом в `border-image` — так можно обойтись без лишней разметки.

```css
.text {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #027abe;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #027abe 0%, transparent 100%) 1;
  border-top:0;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Main content listing header.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь